# How to prevent automatic retain/release when calling Obj-C message from C++?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, objective-c++, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.2

I've got some code like this:

```
@interface MyTimer : NSObject
- (int)getValue;
@end

@interface TimerHolder : NSObject {
    ExternalControl* m_externalControl;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) MyTimer* timer;
@end

class ExternalControl {
    __unsafe_unretained TimerHolder* m_holder;
public:
    ExternalControl(TimerHolder* holder) : m_holder(holder);
    int getTimer() { return [m_holder.timer getValue] };
};
```

The method `ExternalControl::getTimer()` is called very frequently. During profiling, I noticed that during a call to `getTimer()`, obc-j also calls `objc_retain` and `objc_release` (presumably on m_holder or m_holder.timer), which ends up sucking up a lot of time! Removing `__unsafe_unretained` didn't make a difference.

By construction, I know that whenever `ExternalControl::getTimer()` is called, m_holder and its timer will stay alive for the duration of the call, so I think the retains/releases are unnecessary.

Is there any way to prevent them from being called?

I'm using XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 SDK, with ARC enabled. Is ARC responsible and removing it would remove the retains/releases? (I didn't want to spend time re-creating a project without ARC just to test this, before checking with you my friends!)

Comment: To me it looks like this code violates one of the ARC rules, namely do not store oject pointers in C structures (a C++ class counting as a C structure in this instance).  So the proper answer is probably do not use ARC for this file.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Comment: Why not write your answer as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: I can't remember why not.  Perhaps I didn't feel it properly answered the question.  At the time I had done no ARC programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak from a non-ARC experience as I haven't used it yet (and not planning it being old school).

However, I have several projects using a C++ library and keeping references to it in the obj-C code.
I know for a fact that retain/release isn't called unless explicitly requested.

BTW, I couldn't use Obj-C when linking the C++ library and instead had to use Obj-C++ otherwise the C++ constructor/destructors weren't called as expected. It was just a matter of renaming the .m file into .mm

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to point towards ARC as the culprit. Yes I'm using Obj-C++.

Comment: Removed ARC, the extra retains/releases disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually handle retain/release for just that class (disable ARC).
set the "-fno-objc-arc" compiler flag in the build phases tab for that source file.

Answer (score 0):

The WWDC 2011 sessions on ARC specifically mention that when compiled for debug, ARC retain/releases are not optimized.

If you haven't, try running your code in Release mode and profiling it. You should see a significant difference.

However, I know ARC doesn't take into account the kind of design assumptions you imply when you say "By construction". But, ARC shouldn't be touching your your "__unsafe_unretained" instance variable... are you sure those retain/release calls are being passed a pointer to *that*?

Comment: I've just checked, and the "Profile" scheme builds in release mode by default. So I'm guessing they're not optimizing this particular usage of mine... Which seems fair enough since there's no guarantee that my C++ code couldn't run while the Obj-C object has been / is being destroyed, so they can't just remove these retains/releases unless I can somehow tell the compiler of my intentions.

Comment: But your "__unsafe_unretained" is telling it about your intentions... I'd be *shocked* to learn that ARC was trying to retain/release that... that behavior would violate the contract you've setup with it. Something else is going on here.

Comment: From what I understand, __unsafe_unretained tells the compiler that this variables contains a pointer, and that this pointer will not automatically be zeroed if the pointee is destroyed. So it makes sense that the compiler tries to protect the user by retaining the object, thereby preventing a releases while it is being used.

My intent would be to inform the compiler of something more like "__unsafe_retained", in which I *know* that the object must be retained somewhere else, so there's no need to retain it for me please. :-)

Comment: What you want *is* what it does.  If it were me, I wouldn't have given up on using ARC so easily... I think it would serve you well to figure out what was really going on and how to fix it. http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/  "Introducing Automatic Reference Counting" - Slide #45 - Describes `__unsafe_unretained` as: `• Like a traditional variable, or an assign property
• Not initialized
• No extra logic
• No restrictions` The behavior you describe is what `strong` does - not `__unsafe_unretained`. The video makes this explicitly clear.

Comment: I'm still dubious about your claim (or maybe the slide is not strictly correct!?). Reading http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html tells me that `strong` means "retained and zeroing (i.e. pointer becomes 0 when reference is destroyed)", `weak` means "unretained but zeroing", `__unsafe_unretained` means "unretained and non-zeroing". All of these don't say that ObjC may not add a retain/release pair around a message call, which may be optimized out if the compiler knows for sure that the object is retained, as is the case for `strong`.

Comment: Maybe I need to use __unsafe_unretained in the function itself? E.g.: `int getTimer() { __unsafe_unretained MyTimer* t = m_holder.timer; return [t getValue] };` To be investigated... :-)

Comment: Just done the above test, still seeing retains/releases in getTimer().